# Protocol declaration in swift

Tags: swift2

I am new to learning swift and this question might seem very basic to some of you...

```
private protocol abc: class {

    func xyz ()
}
```

In the above protocol declaration why have we written the word “class”. Are we inheriting the protocol “abc” from “class”.

Can someone please throw some light on the above line of code ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID281):

> You can limit protocol adoption to class types (and not structures or
>   enumerations) by adding the class keyword to a protocol’s inheritance
>   list.

This means this `abc` protocol can only be adopted by class types.  If you try to have a structure or enumeration definition use this protocol, you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael. This thing was bugging my mind for so many days. Thanks for the clarification :)